# Should image-paths be stored in the VM with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In a MVVM-scenario the View is responsible for showing the ViewModel. How is does so doesn't matter to the ViewModel.

Now I want to show the value of some property  (e.g a status) with an image (e.g. a trafficlight-like-icon).

Most examples I found stored the path to the different version of the icon in a property in the ViewModel. And changed it depending on the status. And then apply a binding in the view from an image-source to said property.

This doesn't feel right. The ViewModel should not know about the type of rendering for a property. As far as the ViewModel knows it can be rendered as any thing (label, test, image, color, etc).

What is the correct MVVM-WPF method of displaying a ViewModel-property as an image/icon? Thus without storing the image-path/url in the ViewModel.

Comment: You can have a property which contains the (relative or absolute) path to the appropriate image, and bind an element's image-source to it. This way the VM deals with data, not with the type of data.

Comment: With that the VM still is responsible for selecting an image. It think it should not care on how the property is displayed (whether it is an image or label or ...) and thus should not provide an image-path at all.

Comment: It depends on how you look at each layer's responsibilities. I usually put core domain logic in my models because I don't like anemic domain models, but put business logic in viewmodels or in services, really depends on the complexity of the project. What icon will be displayed is related to business logic. Therefore it belongs in the VM. If you don't want to have Uri properties in your VM, replace them with whatever you want and write a converter to convert between that and the Uri for the icon.

Comment: There is no *correct method*. Binding directly to a view model property of type ImageSource is valid MVVM. However, using Binding Converters or DataTriggers is considered cleaner by many people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do this is with a converter in my view.  For example, to convert a status value into an icon, use an enum in the VM and a converter to an icon path.

So in the model we have...

```
    public enum ResultType { Unknown, Good, Bad, Suspect };
    public ResultType Type { get; set; }
```

Then the converter

```
public class ResultTypeIconConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Result.ResultType)
        {
            return GetIconPath((Result.ResultType)value);
        }
        return "Images/glyphicons-195-question-sign.png";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public static string GetIconPath(Result.ResultType rt)
    {
        switch (rt)
        {
            case Result.ResultType.Bad:
                return "pack://application:,,,/someassembly;component/Images/badresult.png";
            case Result.ResultType.Good:
                return "pack://application:,,,/someassembly.WPF;component/Images/goodresult.png";
            case Result.ResultType.Suspect:
                return "pack://application:,,,/someassembly.WPF;component/Images/suspectresult.png";
            case Result.ResultType.Unknown:
                return "pack://application:,,,/someassembly.WPF;component/Images/unknownresult.png";
            default:
                return "pack://application:,,,/PetroUtilitiesUI.WPF;component/Images/glyphicons-195-question-sign.png";
        }
    }
}
```

XAML resource

```
    <local:ResultTypeIconConverter x:Key="IconConverter"/>
```

XAML reference

```
    <Image Height="15" Width="15"  Source="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource IconConverter}}" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
```

So this is very clean.  The model doesn't know anything about icons and the view doesn't know anything about enums.  Now...is a type converter part of the VM or the view?  I leave this question to the philosophers.

Comment: The other "right way" would be a set of DataTriggers instead of a Binding Converter.

Comment: @Clemens - to be honest I consider DataTriggers to almost always be the right way here because it puts the visual concern we are dealing with in the XAML file which is where that stuff belongs.  Where would a dedicated UX designer using Blend put it?  Not in C# code....